# Factorize a matrix from a given set of matrices

Tags: combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, finite-groups

Let's assume I have a matrix M and a set of other matrices S. In every row of these matrices there is exactly one entry with 1, the others are 0.

Now I want to represent M as a product of matrices from S, i.e. I want to know which matrices from S I have to multiply to get M. Any matrix from S may be used multiple times.

Possible solutions could look like $M = S[2] * S[3]$ or $M = S[0] * S[1] * S[0] * S[5]$. I'd prefer the solution with the minimum number of multiplications.

---

Questions/Notes:

1. Does this problem have any name? Googling for matrix factorization doesn't lead anywhere.
2. What's a good way to approach this problem? For very small sizes of S and dimensions of M I wrote a small program that enumerates all the possible matrices that can be created from S and then halts if the matrix is M.  This does not scale for bigger numbers, especially if the number of multiplications in the solution gets bigger. Is there some efficient algorithm to solve this problem?
3. I've visualized these matrices as bipartite graphs which gave me some insights, e.g. matrix S1 in the example below will map two of the inputs (row 1 and row 3) to the same output. Then I looked at [matrix similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to find the "structure" of the matrix/graph independent of its bases and tried to exploit that to limit the possible multiplication combinations I have to look at.
4. Please bear in mind I'm not a professional mathematician so I'd prefer a simple phrased answer if possible :-)
5. [EDIT] I just found out S is probably called a [finite generating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_group).

Thanks for your answers!

---

Example

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\\0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

S containing 3 matrices:

$$S1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$S2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\\0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$S3 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Solution:

$$M = S1 * S3 * S2$$

Comment: You might look up Reachability problem on wikipedia.

Comment: @anthonyquas Thanks so much, this looks exactly like the problem I'm facing